# Filter several Groups to show using LDAP

Tags: ldap

I'm using LAM (LDAP Account Manager) and I have several server profiles. So some profiles should only see for example three groups width the GIDs 300, 301 and 302.

There is an input field which defines the filter. Currently I'm using            `(gidNumber=300)`, and it shows only users witht the GID 300.

How is it possible to show also the users with the GID 301 and those with the GID 302?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive what you are looking for.
Try something like

> (&(gidNumber>=300)(gidNumber<=322))

-jim